# How to change folder-path which saved image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6

I'm trying to change folderpath which saved image. (from myfolder to yourfolder) 
My wrote code is like following.

When I execute following code, it's occurs error.
I think it's trying to load from folder before change.

How to load image file from changed folder?
Please help. :o

```
// image loading.
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm.png"];
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
imageView1.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:imageView1];

// get document path.
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *appsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [appsDirectory objectAtIndex:0];

// create myFolder path.
NSString *myFolderPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFolder"];
if ([fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:myFolderPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil]){
    NSLog(@"success");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"failed");
}

// write image to saveImage@2x.png file.
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1)];

NSString *saveName = @"saveImage@2x.png";
NSString *savePath = [myFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveName];
[imageData writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];


// load from saved the image1 to image2
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savePath];


// change folderpath from myfolder to yourfolder
NSString *yourFolderPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFolder"];
if ([fileManager moveItemAtPath:myFolderPath toPath:yourFolderPath error:NULL]){
    NSLog(@"USER folder success");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"USER folder fail");
}

// attach image2 to self.view
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image2];
imageView.center = CGPointMake(100, 200);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];


// it's occurs error.
```

Following is log list.

2012-12-02 17:56:31.273 FolderTest[3372:11303] success 
2012-12-02 17:56:31.277 FolderTest[3372:11303] USER folder success 
ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/Users/nice7285/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/757CBD0E-CB49-4385-AF10-27322FB98381/Documents/myFolder/saveImage@2x.png'
         error = 2 (No such file or directory) 
ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/Users/nice7285/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/757CBD0E-CB49-4385-AF10-27322FB98381/Documents/myFolder/saveImage@2x.png'
         error = 2 (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am not really sure but i have some suggestions

try to change the create folder line to look like this

```
[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
```

use this function to write data

```
NSError *error;
[imageData writeToFile:savePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

i hope that help

Answer (score 0):

This is not error of Not creating directories but this error occur because you save your image to sandbox without allocation

Solution:-

```
// write image to saveImage@2x.png file.
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1)];

NSString *saveName = @"saveImage@2x.png";
NSString *savePath = [myFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveName];
[imageData writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
```

and also fetch using allocated object ex.

```
// load from saved the image1 to image2

UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:savePath];
```